# Can not Communicate with UI Thread

Tags: android, handler, rpc, protocol-buffers, ui-thread

I made a simple RPC mechanism apps for android and I faced a problem that I can not go back to the UI Thread from RPC class.

Basically I have 3 classes(ServerActivity,ServerView and ServiceImplementation), I created 3 classes because I use RPC and Protocol Buffer for drawing.

Server Activity :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    _sv = new ServerView(this);
    setContentView(_sv);

    rpcConnectionFactory = SocketRpcConnectionFactories.createServerRpcConnectionFactory(SERVER_PORT);
    int nThreadPool = 1;
    server = new RpcServer(rpcConnectionFactory, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreadPool), true);
    server.registerBlockingService(Service.newReflectiveBlockingService(new ServiceImpl(myServiceHandler)));
    server.run();
}

Handler myServiceHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.i("Handler", "Handler IN");
        _sv.set(msg.what); /*To communicate with the view*/
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};
```

ServiceImplementation :

```
public CanvasServiceImpl(Handler mActivity) {
    backToUIThread = mActivity;
}
public Response drawCircle(RpcController controller, Circle1 request)
        throws ServiceException {
    android.os.Message message = new android.os.Message();
    message.what = 1;
    ImplHandler.sendMessage(message);
    Response response = Response.newBuilder().setResult("drawCircle Success").build();
    return response;
}
```

I can not reach my UI Thread. Does anybody know why ?

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
ImplHandler.sendMessage(message);
```

use

```
backToUIThread.sendMessage(message);
```